# Can IdentityServer be used in this setup

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I am trying to understand if I can use IdentityServer for my setup.

I need to create a system with an authentication service, where other products can login.

The idea is to use SSO which would allow me to login with one product, and then use another product without signing in.

The problem is that I need to have a separate session for every login and if, for instance, I login to a ProductA and there is a session created(in my auth service), when I then open ProductB, a request is made to the authntication service with a session id from productA, the auth service checks this session id and creates a separate session id for productb, so it is not a classic SSO. Would it be possible to achieve with IdentityServer?

Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not clear enough to understand what you are trying to do. In particular "separate session for every login" can have multiple meanings and your example doesn't help much here. You will either get no answers or worse, people will vote to close this as unclear.

Comment: Hm, thanks, I thought it was clear. I meant that every session is Products (A,B) should result in a session in AuthService. I have never worked with IdentityServer and for me it is not clear how much control do I have over the  communication. For instance the following flow: 1. I open productA, it sees there is not cookie and redirect me to auth service 2. Authservice checks my credentials, creates a session and returns a specific token to productA, 3. I open productB it sees that there is a cookie for productA, it gets a token and sends it to auth service. 4. Authservice gets the token etc.

Comment: It doesn't work like this and never will. ProductB will never be able to see if there is a cookie for ProductA. Rather, all three have their own cookies, ProductA, ProductB and the AuthServer. The flow differs then from the one you present in step 3: You open ProductB, it sees that there is no cookie for ProductB so it goes to auth service. 4. Authservice has already the cookie so it doesn't present the login page, rather it returns the token without any user interaction. 5. ProductB creates its own cookie.

Comment: Right, because of different domains. You're right, you actually described the flow that I had in mind. The question is would IdentityServer help me achieving it, or I am better off using Auth0, or write everything from scratch?

Comment: The flow is common to SSO protocols and it will definitely work in a similar way with the IdentityServer.